# The PID and name of the program to which socket belongs

Tags: linux, networking, port, netstat

Using 'netstat -tulp' on my server box running under CentOS I have discovered strange listening ports 33363 (TCP) and 35661 (UDP). The thing is that 'PID/Program name' field for these ports contains nothing (dash actually). 'fuser -n tcp 33363' shows nothing. I have checked my box with chkrootkit and rkhunter utilities and it seems everything is O.K.
Does anybody know what these sockets can be used for?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried with **lsof**?

```
lsof -i TCP:33363
lsof -i UDP:35661
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Like 'fuser' 'lsof' gives an empty output.

Comment: Pretty weird...

You can also try to trace the pid and see if it shows something interesting:

 strace -p <PID>

Comment: What PID, Fran?

Comment: Doh! True, we do not know the pid. Thanks for pointing it out Manni :)

Comment: Unfortunately `lsof` seems to usable only by root. My process is running as user "foo". I am user "foo", can get no results. Stragen. The tool `nestat` shows the open ports.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `netstat -tulp` as `root`?

Comment: Could have been the reason for the missing pid. You never know ;-)